# How to set captured image in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have an ArrayList which is bound to the listview, the custom row has a textview and an imageview, now when I click on any row I have given two functionality 
1. Toast message to display position: which is displaying properly.
2. Open camera to capture an image and set that particular image to the row which was clicked.

Now the problem which I am facing is :

The image gets set but always to the last row and not to the row where it was clicked and when I click on the last row to capture image while setting the image it says `IndexOutofBoundException`

The code I have tried :

```
public class DocumentsKYCAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<DocumentItem> gridName;
    ArrayList<Integer> selectedDocumentId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> selectedDocumentNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> selectedImages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    private Bitmap[] gridImage;
    Documents_KYC activity;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Imageview";
    private Uri fileUri;
    ImageView imageView;
    public static byte[] b;
    public static String encodedImageStr1;
    int imageCapturedPosition;

    public DocumentsKYCAdapter(Documents_KYC activity, 
    ArrayList<DocumentItem> gridName,ArrayList<Integer> 
    selectedDocumentId,ArrayList<String> selectedDocumentNames) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.gridImage = gridImage;
        this.gridName = gridName;
        this.selectedDocumentNames = selectedDocumentNames;
        this.selectedDocumentId = selectedDocumentId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return selectedDocumentNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
    parent) {

        View grid;


        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.documents_kyc_row, null);

        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        final String documentItemName = 
        selectedDocumentNames.get(position);
        final int documentItemId = selectedDocumentId.get(position);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.gridName);
        imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.gridImage);
        imageView.setTag(position);
        textView.setText(documentItemName);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                imageCapturedPosition = position;
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Id"+documentItemId+"
               ,Position"+imageCapturedPosition,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).
                show();
                imageView.getTag(position);
                captureImage();
            }
        });


        return grid;
    }

    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
    data) {

        try {
            if (requestCode == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE && resultCode == 
                activity.RESULT_OK) {

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new 
                BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 1;
                Bitmap bitmap = Utility.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), 
                options);
                FileOutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(fileUri.getPath());
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new 
                    ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, 
                    baos);
                    b = baos.toByteArray();
                    encodedImageStr1 = Base64.encodeToString(b, 
                    Base64.DEFAULT);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                selectedImages.add(bitmap);          
                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImages.
                get(imageCapturedPosition));


            } else if (resultCode == activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,
                        "User cancelled image capture", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity,
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", 
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

}
```

Custom Class :

```
public class BitmapModel {

Bitmap imageId;
ArrayList<String> documentNamesList;

public ArrayList<String> getDocumentNamesList() {
    return documentNamesList;
}

public void setDocumentNamesList(ArrayList<String> documentNamesList) {
    this.documentNamesList = documentNamesList;
}

public Bitmap getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}

public void setImageId(Bitmap imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the line -

```
selectedImages.add(bitmap);
```

Here whenever you add an image to your arrayList it always adds at the last position and then when you do `imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImages.get(imageCapturedPosition));` It tries to get the value for the position you selected which is not necessarily the last position.

The better way for you to do is create a Custom Class with `Bitmap` and `selectedDocumentNames` as part of the class then each object of the class would represent a name and an image associated with it.

Now when you capture the image, assign the image to the class Bitmap and then populate your listview with that Bitmap.

The workaround for your present code code be to either add the image into a particular position in array denoted by `imageCapturedPosition` or create a `hashmap` of type `position,bitmap` and then store it with the selected position. though i would not recommend any of these workarounds as they would cause other problems in future like memory leaks and positional movements in arrays etc and you would have to take care of these things

Comment: Thank you for replying , i have created a custom class as i have updated it in my question , but can you tell me whether i need to create a list of bitmaps or just a bitmap object ??

Comment: It depends on your requirement. If you want to have just 1 image per row then only single object is enough inside the model class. then you need to have a list of model class objects to save data and populate listview